# Android 4.3: App spawns many processes on sync

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, remote-process

On the Samsung S3 with Android 4.3, my Android app spawns new processes on every sync request using the `SyncAdapter`. The processes survive the "Force stop" button in the system's app settings and even an uninstall of the app. Only after a reboot, the processes are gone.

On an Android 4.3 simulator, this behavior is not reproducible.

On regular devices, our app is running in two processes (one for the app and one foreground service).

Has anyone heard of this beavior before? Might be a Samsung-specific issue. We have never seen this behavior on any other Android device.